# sql return 1st day of each month in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table like so with two columns...

3/1/17    100

3/2/17    200

3/3/17    300

4/3/17    600

4/4/17    700

4/5/17    800

I am trying to run a query that returns the 1st day of each month in that above table, and grab the corresponding value.

results should be

3/1/17   100

4/3/17   600

then once I have these results... do something with each one.
any ideas how I can get started?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard SQL, you would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by extract(year from dte), extract(month from dte)
                                order by dte asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Most databases support this functionality, but the exact functions (particularly for dates) may differ depending on the database.

Comment: i'm using microsoft sql server 2016... doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @solarissf - For SQL Server, the syntax of the row_number portion would be `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, dte), DATEPART(MONTH, dte) ORDER BY dte) as seqnum`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (SQL Server flavour):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
JOIN (
    select MIN(DateColumn) as MinimumDate
    from YourTable
    group by FORMAT(DateColumn,'yyyyMM')
) q on (t.DateColumn = q.MinimumDate)
ORDER BY t.DateColumn;
```

For the GROUP BY this will also be fine:

```
group by YEAR(DateColumn), MONTH(DateColumn)
```

or

```
group by DATEPART(YEAR,DateColumn), DATEPART(MONTH,DateColumn)
```